# random underscore shows up on a href list item

Tags: php, html

I have some code here

http://jsfiddle.net/38ULH/

why is there an underscore between each element? I want the whole list item to be clickable, that is why ahref is on the outside of li.

```
 <a href="itemDetail.php"><li class="ui-state-default" id="<?php echo $id;?>">
 <input type="button" class="removeItem" value="remove">
 <input type="text" name="itemName" id="itemName" value="hat">
 <select name="itemPicker">
 <option value=""></option>
 <?php
                            foreach ($sizes as $value)
                            {

                                    echo "<option value='" . $value . "'" . $sel . ">" . $value . "</option>";
                            }
 ?>
 </select>
 </li></a>
```

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. Why apply href to whole item including drop-down select element?

Comment: yea, terrible original design....

Comment: not the end of the world :), at least you got your question answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't underscores. That is the hyperlink underscore.

Why are you applying a link to the entire list? It's invalid html and bad for user experience.

Comment: my thought was user clicks anywhere on list item to get next page. I suppose an item detail button may be more appropriate.  thanks

Answer (score 3):

The underscore is the standard underlining of links, utilize css to remove it:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

or directly in the tag

```
<a href="itemDetail.php" style="text-decoration: none;">
```